# Grails build list of usernames from database

Tags: grails

I am trying to build an alphabetically sorted list of user names from my User objects in the database. Im finding that all the different ways of list() only returns the entire User objects. I just need their usernames which is a property of each User. I need to feed this list to a g:select pull down list on my gsp. Can't seem to put the code together. I am using Mongodb but that shouldn't really matter I know. Here's my algorithm.

Iterate through the user collection and grab the property username on each.
collect all usernames into list then alphabetically sort it
feed it to the g:select list

maybe something like

```
list userList = User.list()
list usernameList

usernameList << a groovy loop to collect it.username(s)
```

and then alphabetically sort usernameList then feed it to g:select.

Comment: You can use method collect - see http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect%28groovy.lang.Closure%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is a shorter way `userlist = User.list().collect{it.username}.sort(java.text.Collator.instance)`

Comment: this will work, but you will retrieve all the fields from the database and then filter them and  never use many of them, in big apps this might cause you performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) create custom query, just create a hql query and then use the method executeQuery:

http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html

```
User.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM User u order by u.username asc")
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution

```
def usersList = User.list().username.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way to do it:

```
    userlist = User.list()
    def userlist2 = []
    userlist.each { userlist2 << it.username }
    userlist2.sort()
    userlist = userlist2
```

Now userlist is ready as you need it to be fed into g:select

Comment: That is way longer than necessary